# Are this formulae for downvotes and upvotes correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was curious what my number of downvotes and upvotes on a post was, and wondered if I could derive utility from the information Reddit provided. This solution is applicable when the number of upvotes is no less than the number of downvotes.

---

Let the $\%$ of upvotes be $k$.
Let the net vote be $n$.
Let the number of upvotes be $u$.
Let the number of downvotes be $d$.
Let the total number of votes be $T$.

$$T = u + d \tag{0}$$
$$n = u - d \, \forall \, u \ge d \tag{1}$$
$$u = \frac{k}{100}(T)$$
$$u = \frac{k}{100}(u + d) \tag{2}$$
$$n = \frac{k}{100}(u + d) - d$$
$$n = \frac{k(u + d) - 100d}{100}$$
$$n = \frac{ku + kd - 100d)}{100} \tag{3}$$
$$u - d = \frac{ku + kd - 100d)}{100} \tag{3.1}$$

Multiply through by $100$ and expand:
$$100u - 100d = ku  + kd - 100d$$

Collect like terms:
$$100u - ku = 100d + kd - 100d$$ 
$$100u - ku = kd$$

Simplify:
$$u(100 - k)  = kd$$

Make $u$ the subject of the formula:
$$u = \frac{kd}{100 - k} \tag{4}$$

Substitute $(4)$ into $(1)$:
$$n = \left(\frac{kd}{100 - k} - d\right)$$
$$n = \frac{kd - d(100 - k)}{100 - k}$$
$$n = \frac{d(k - 100 + k)}{100 - k}$$
$$n= \frac{d(2k - 100)}{100 - k}$$

Make $d$ the subject of the formula:
$$d(2k - 100) = n(100 - k)$$
$$d = \frac{n(100 - k)}{(2k - 100)} \tag{5}$$

Substitute $(5)$ into $(4)$:
$$u = k\left(\frac{n(100 - k)}{(2k - 100)}\right) \times \frac{1}{100 - k}$$
$$u = \frac{kn}{2k - 100} \tag{6}$$

Substitute $(5)$ and $(6)$ into $(0)$:
$$T = \frac{kn}{2k - 100} + \frac{n(100 - k)}{(2k - 100)}$$
$$T = \frac{kn + n(100 - k)}{2k - 100}$$
$$T = \frac{n(k + 100 - k)}{2k - 100}$$
$$T = \frac{100n}{2k - 100}$$
$$Q.E.D$$

---

Comment: might be better asked in meta.

Comment: This is about Reddit upvotes and downvotes, not SE.